# How can I read an image from memory in Matlab? (instead of imread)

Tags: matlab, imread

I'm trying to get an image from buffer memory into Matlab.

For example in C++ and openCV I can get image from memory with;

```
fn_export double ImgFromMem(char* address,double width, double height) {
    Mat image = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, address);
```

in Matlab ;

```
Img1=imread('testimage.png');
figure,imshow(Img1),title('Original')
[Height, Width, Depth]=size(Img1);
```

I want to assign Img1 as an image but from memory like C++ example above.

Any idea about this?

Comment: How do you have the data stored in MATLAB?

Comment: Where does the data come from? Do you have the memory address where this is stored? If you're trying to access the memory of another process, you might encounter a segfault. Please clarify the use case, which other tools you're using, how does the image end up in memory in the first place, and any additional information that could help us identify a solution (since this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)).